# Use the principle of mathematical induction to show that the given statement is true for all natural numbers n.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction, solution-verification

Use the principle of mathematical induction to show that the given statement is true for all natural numbers n.

$S_n: 11+23+35+...+(12n-1)=n(6n+5)$

**My work:**

$S_1:(12*1-1) \overset?= 1(6*1+5)$

$11 = 11$

$S_k:11+23+35+...+(12k-1)=k(6k+5)$
$S_{k+1}: 11+23+35+...+(12k-1)+12(k+1)-1 \overset?= (k+1)[6(k+1)+5]$

$(12k-1)+1+12k+11 \overset?=(k+1)(6k+11)$

I want to verify that all my work up to this point is correct. Especially the last line, which should be expressed in factored form. Thank you!

Comment: The left-hand side of the last line should be $k(6k + 5) + (12k+1)$. Dunno how you arrived at the expression you wrote, but it can't be right, there's a $k^2$ term missing there.

Comment: @fgp Ah, yes. That's the part I thought I messed up. Wouldn't it be: $k(6k+5)+12k+11$ ?

Comment: $S_{k+1}=S_{k}+12(k+1)-1=k(6k+5)+12(k+1)-1=6k^2+12k+12+5k-1=6(k^2+2k+1)+5(k+1)=6(k+1)^2+5(k+1)$

Comment: error, the lhs of the last line should be $k(6k+5) + 12(k+1) - 1 = 6k^2 + 5k +12k + 11$ from here it is an easy factorization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We want to prove that $$
  11 + 23 + 35 + \ldots + (12n - 1) = n(6n + 5) \text{.}
$$

We start with the *base case* $n=1$, i.e. we have to validate $$
  11 \overset?= 1(6\cdot 1 + 5)
$$
which is indeed true.

Now we *assume* that the statement is true for some $n$ (the *induction hypothesis*), and *using that assumption* prove that it's also true for $n+1$. This is the *induction step*. In other words, we have to show that $$
  11 + \ldots + (12n - 1) = n(6n + 5) \Rightarrow \underbrace{11 + \ldots + (12(n+1) - 1)}_{A} = \underbrace{(n+1)(6(n+1) + 5)}_{B} \text{.}
$$
We do that by observing that $$\begin{eqnarray}
  A &=& 11 + \ldots + (12(n+1) - 1) \\
  &=& \underbrace{11 + \ldots + (12n - 1)}_{=n(6n + 5) \,(\star)} + (12(n+1) - 1) \\
  &=& 6n^2 + 5n + 12n + 12 - 1 \\
  &=& 6n^2 + 17n + 11
\end{eqnarray}$$
and that also $$\begin{eqnarray}
  B &=& (n+1)(6(n+1) + 5) \\
  &=& (n+1)(6n + 11)\\
  &=& 6n^2 + 11n + 6n + 11 \\
  &=& 6n^2 + 17n + 11 \text{.}
\end{eqnarray}$$
So $A=B$, which completes the proof of the induction step. $(\star)$ is where we used the *induction hypothesis*.

Comment: I think undergrad's solution is a bit more slick personally, but this is equally valid.

Comment: @fgp This is what I initially got as well, but how in the world do I fit it into this format? http://imgur.com/4o00Pwd
I truly appreciate the effort.

Comment: @user125736 That left-hand side in that image *already* uses the assumption as far as I can see. All that's missing is factoring out the $(k+1)$ term. But whoever forces you to do solve math problems but typing seemingly arbitrary stuff into some form must be quite ouf of this mind.... This is horrible!

Comment: @fgp So k(6k+5) in the first box?

Comment: @user125736 There just isn't enough context there.... Is that an image of the *whole* question? And what are the blue boxes?

Comment: @fgp Answers go in the blue boxes: http://imgur.com/MsowoiP

Comment: @user125736 $k(6k+5)$ seems sensible... But again, this is an absolutely *gruesome* way to teach induction proofs. I'm appalled!

Comment: @fgp Well, the first time, before I even asked this question, I entered exactly the answers you provided in your work and it marked it wrong. So, yeah, it's not doing me any favors. I've completed this entire section but I'm still stuck on this silly thing.